# Trouble getting Users IP

Tags: php

The form action is linked to this php script:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['subscribefield'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "Dit adres klopt niet";
  die();
}

$to = "flash1996mph@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
$body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "U bent succesvol aangemeld voor de Vandenberg nieuwsbrief";
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

At the end i added `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` then i checked my mail, but there was nothing. Did i use the code the wrong way?

EDIT:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['subscribefield'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "Dit adres klopt niet";
  die();
}


$to = "flash1996mph@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
$body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";
$body .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "U bent succesvol aangemeld voor de Vandenberg nieuwsbrief";
?>
```

The above is an edit^

Comment: `$body` is the content of the email.

Comment: It might be marked as spam, because you're missing the headers. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail -- also, are you running this on localhost or on a server somewhere? If the mail is sent, but you can't see the IP, it's because the IP isn't added into the `$body` variable, so it will not be sent with the mail. See the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation

Comment: Oh i got the mail but it did not display the ip @Qirel

Comment: thre was No ip @chris85

Comment: Like @chris85 pointed out first (beat me to the punch there ;-) ), the IP isn't part of the `$body` variable, so it will not be sent. Before the `mail()` call, add `$body .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and you'll see it.

Comment: PHP can't time travel. You don't access the REMOTE_ADDR until **AFTER** you sent the email.

Comment: worked fine for me.

Comment: did u get an IP @Fred-ii-

Comment: weird i just get an email with 2 things

Comment: @KevinAartsen I sure have. Make sure you uploaded the right file and that you're not victim of caching here. Your form does use the POST method, right?

Comment: Gosh i feel so stupid.. i was certain i had saved! but i didn't.. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @KevinAartsen Ah... had a feeling about that ;-) not bad huh? *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is called the email is sent. In your script `$body` is the body of the email so append the IP address on to that variable before you call the `mail` function.

```
$to = "flash1996mph@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
$body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";
$body .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

The `echo` currently just outputs the IP on the browser.

Comment: i added that now and still nothing just a mail only displaying this:$body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

Comment: hehe i forgot to save :l

Comment: [*Seems like I hit the nail right on the head...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733295/trouble-getting-users-ip?noredirect=1#comment62938619_37733295) hehe ;-)